# Find the reference angle

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

This is a fairly simple question. According to [this random website I found — Web Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20161121045247/http://www.regentsprep.org:80/regents/math/algtrig/ATT3/referenceAngles.htm), a reference angle is `the acute angle formed by the terminal side of the given angle and the x-axis.` You have to write a program to find these.

### I don't remember anything from algebra 2, what does this mean?

Angles are usually given in **standard form**, which is measured by placing one side of the angle and measuring to the other side, counterclockwise, like so:

[image: Standard form]

This will be your input. Your output will be the reference angle of this. You can think of this as basically the smallest distance from the terminal side to the x-axis. Except it's an angle, not a distance. Here are some examples:

[image: Quad 2 ref]  [image: Quad 1 ref]

[image: Quad 3 ref]  [image: Quad 4 ref]

### Clarifications

- All the defaults on inputs and submissions.
- Angles is in **degrees**.
- Negative angles, non-integer angles, and angles > 360 deg **are** allowed.
- Output in form `60 deg`.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

[Another helpful link](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/trigonometry/reference-angle/finding-reference-angle.php).

### Test Cases

```
70      ->  70 deg
135     ->  45 deg
210     ->  30 deg
-60     ->  60 deg
91      ->  89 deg
610     ->  70 deg
-1000   ->  80 deg
```

Comment: What do we do on input of 90?

Comment: @ThomasKwa it would be 90 from either direction.

Comment: A short solution is `abs(arcsin(sin(input)))+" deg"`, though I don't know which language would win (it would need to support degrees and string operations).

Comment: Is the input always an integer?

Comment: @ThomasKwa good point, no.

Comment: Since non-integer angles are allowed, you should include one in the test cases.

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, 17 bytes

```
+hS%R180,Q_Q" deg
```

Coincidentally, this is equivalent to [@xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53770/20080).

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BhS%25R180%2CQ_Q%22%20deg&input=-1000&debug=0)

Answer (score 6):

### Pyth, 18 bytes

```
+.a-%+QK90yKK" deg
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B.a-%25%2BQK90yKK%22+deg&debug=0)

Comment: got it down to 19 using your algo but with inline assign, feel free to use: https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B.a-%25%2BvwK90yKK%22+deg&debug=0

Comment: @Maltysen: Thanks, found another improvement as well

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 34 bytes

```py
lambda x:`90-abs(x%180-90)`+' deg'
```

Using `"%d deg"` string formatting would be longer because of the needed parentheses.

Answer (score 5):

### CJam (21 bytes)

```
180qd1$%z_@@-e<" deg"
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=180qd1%24%25z_%40%40-e%3C%22%20deg%22&input=610)

Answer (score 4):

## dc, 25

```
90?90+d*v180%-d*vn[ deg]p
```

Note `dc` uses `_` as a -ve sign instead of `-`.

#### Test output:

```
$ for test in 70 135 210 _60 91 610 _1000; do dc -e'90?90+d*v180%-d*vn[ deg]p' <<< $test ; done
70 deg
45 deg
30 deg
60 deg
89 deg
70 deg
80 deg
$
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, 35

```python
lambda x:`min(x%180,-x%180)`+' deg'
```

The smaller of the angle and its negative modulo `180`. Effectively converts the angle to the range from 0 to 180 and takes the distance to the closer of the endpoints. Note that `-x%180` groups as `(-x)%180`.

Same length with string formatting for Python 3:

```python
lambda x:'%d deg'%min(x%180,-x%180)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>22</s> 31

```
ToString@Abs@Mod[#,180,-90]deg&
```

Comment: @LegionMammal978 If I just multiply it by `deg`, `0 deg` will become `0`.

Comment: Since you don't care about the output type, you can save 2 bytes like this: `Row@{Abs@Mod[#,180,-90],deg}&`

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth <del>25</del> 30 bytes

Painfully uncreative solution, using trig functions. [Permalink](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B.R.t.a.t.t.tQ7Z3+6%3F%25Q1Q0%22+deg&input=-1000.5&debug=0)

```
+.R.t.a.t.t.tQ7Z3 6?%Q1Q0" deg
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Got it down to 28 by taking the `.t` calls and putting them in a fold: `+.R.t.a.tF[Q7Z3)6?%Q1Q0" deg`

Comment: Neat. I noticed it doesn't appear to work with a floating point input: `90.5 => 90.0 deg`, though.

Comment: That's because yours doesn't either: https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B.R.t.a.t.t.tQ7Z3+6%3F%25Q1Q0%22+deg&input=90.5&debug=0

Comment: Interesting catch. With input `-60.5 => 60.5 deg` but with `60.5 => 60.0 deg`. Looks like an issue with Pyth -- [Example using pyth/macros.py](http://i.imgur.com/XIJaJo2.png)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes

Similar to [Sp3000's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53772/22867), though the modulo is quite lengthy [due to the behaviour in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4467539/404623).

```
f=x=>90-Math.abs((x%180+180)%180-90)+' deg'
```

#### Demo

Code is rewritten in ES5 for browser compatibility:

```js
function f(x){return 90-Math.abs((x%180+180)%180-90)+' deg'}

// Snippet stuff
console.log = function(x){document.body.innerHTML += x + '<br>'};
[70,135,210,-60,91,610,-1000].map(function(v){console.log(f(v))});
```

### CoffeeScript, 45 bytes

```
f=(x)->90-Math.abs((x%180+180)%180-90)+' deg'
```

Comment: I assume it was a design decision by a PDP hardware engineer which is responsible for the fact that several decades later we still have very few languages which implement `%` sensibly.

Comment: Replacing the first 180 with `(t=180)` then replacing the following 180s with t would probably save a few bytes

Comment: @vihan1086 It's the same

Answer (score 1):

## J, 26 bytes

```
m=:180&|
' deg',~m@-":@<.m
```

Same as [xnor's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53770/31405).

Answer (score 1):

### Matlab, 44

Using an anonymous function:

```
f=@(x)[num2str(min(mod([x -x],180))) ' deg']
```

Example:

```
>> f=@(x)[num2str(min(mod([x -x],180))) ' deg']
f = 
    @(x)[num2str(min(mod([x,-x],180))),' deg']

>> f(70)
ans =
70 deg

>> f(210)
ans =
30 deg

>> f(-1000)
ans =
80 deg
```

Comment: This doesn't append the ' deg' at the end though. (Did not downvote.)

Comment: @Legendre Oops. Thanks! Corrected

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <s>40</s> 35 Characters

```
(a:Int)⇒s"${90-(a%180-90).abs} deg"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 83 bytes

```
proc R a {puts [expr [set a $a%360]>90?$a>180?$a>270?360-$a:$a-180:180-$a:$a]\ deg}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc0xDoMwDAXQPaf4QzpGckANhQHuwEoZLBp1oWoEqVQJ5eypUwZ/67/Bjsuac9jeC0YwjvCJOyb/DRum3UchzZfa0dy3NGju7e2/qoYGUaO502wEO5mzzXc8/DPl9cWhXFQNAVC2vkpWVooyrmRri7tTLBGphGOUfyn/AA)

Answer (score -1):

### PHP, 44 bytes

Takes one command line parameter. Again [PHP suffers from the same issue as JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409281/how-is-13-64-13-in-php).

```php
<?=90-abs(($argv[1]%180+180)%180-90)+' deg';
```

Using the canonical solution requires 53 bytes (the degrees and radians conversion takes a lot of characters):

```php
<?=rad2deg(abs(asin(sin(deg2rad($argv[1])))))+' deg';
```

Comment: Doesn't PHP use `.` for concatenation?

Comment: @vihan1086 Yes, PHP uses `.`. Downvoted until it is fixed